# await raises SyntaxError when the function called has the async keyword: Python

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I have a function with the `async` keyword in a separate script, which is this:

```
async def search_gifs(self, query:str, limit:int = 25, offset:int = 0, rating: rating = rating.G, lang:language = None):
    if language == None:
        lang_to_use = self.lang
    result = await requests.get(self.end_point + "gifs/search", api_key = self.key, q = query, limit=limit, offset=offset, rating=rating.value, lang=lang_to_use.value)
    print(result.json())
```

However, when I try calling it with an `await`, it raises a `SintaxError`.

```
await client.search_gifs("lol")

>>> await client.search_gifs("lol")
               ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

(`search_gifs` is a function inside the `Client` class)

Am I doing something wrong? I'm using Python 3.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`await` is only valid inside an `async def`, so it doesn't work at top-level. This is because the contract of `await` is that it must be able to *suspend* the current coroutine, and at top-level there is no coroutine to suspend.

To test a coroutine from the interpreter, use [`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) or, in Python 3.6, [`run_until_complete`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_until_complete):

```
>>> asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(client.search_gifs("lol"))
```

The other problem with your code is that `await requests.get(...)` won't work, since `requests` is not an async library. Instead, use an asyncio-aware library such as [`aiohttp`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp).